# Set Internet Explorer as the default browser from the command line

Tags: windows, browser, internet-explorer, cmd.exe

Is it possible to set Internet Explorer as the default browser to launch from the command line?

I have a web application that only runs under Internet Explorer, but if it happens that Firefox is the default browser, it doesn't work. Users are in a domain environment and even though I try to launch our application from a batch in this way:

```
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://server_ip/home_page
```

the application doesn't start unless I change the browser manually.

Comment: I suppose "fix the app so that it actually honors proper html instead of breaking under every decent browser" isn't an option?

Comment: @Shadur There are some spheres where problems are viewed as features..

Comment: Relying on broken behavior specific to a single browser is not, or at least should never be, a feature.

Comment: @techie007 I didn't test it myself but you can check out [here](http://forums.techguy.org/7821594-post7.html) and [here](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/830086-any-way-to-launch-the-default-browser-from-the-command-line/#entry591667836).

Comment: Making IE default browser is a bad idea.

Comment: To bad none of the answers worked for me, e-mailed IT to hopefully utilize GPO but more likely I will end up doing this manually for my end users.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This command will set IE as the default browser:

```
shmgrate.exe OcinstallreinstallIE
```

[This policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms814865.aspx) should stop people determining the default browser.

Comment: No probs. Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: +1 for the policy as well.

Comment: In Windows Vista the registration scheme was overhauled. The `shmgrate` tool is only available in Windows 2000/XP and Windows Server 2003. Also, that policy will just prevent Internet Explorer from checking whether it's set as the default browser.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this, it will work

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://server_ip/home_page
```

the error in your command was that `start` expects first quoted string to be the title of the application, which in this case you can leave empty.

for setting `iexplorer.exe` as system's default web browser, you can use `assoc` and `ftype` commands, which associate extensions with file types, and file types with executable files, like so:

```
assoc .html=htmlfile
ftype htmlfile="C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" %1
```

`%1` is the argument here - that is the URL or the file that you can send to the program as an input

Comment: (Just) Associating the HTML file type to be opened by IE is not the same as setting it to be the OS's default browser.

Comment: iexplore.exe, not iexplorer.exe

Answer (score 1):

## Windows Vista and later, IE 7+

The following batch script simulates clicking **Set this programs as default** from the Default Programs control panel applet. Tested with Vista/7 and IE 7/IE 11.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM -- check XHTML support (IE 9+)
set xhtml=0
for /f %%G in ('"reg query "HKCR\IE.AssocFile.XHT" /ve 2>&1 | findstr /c:".XHT" "') do set xhtml=1

REM -- reset file extensions
set exts=HTM,HTML
if %xhtml% == 1 (set exts=%exts%,XHT,XHTML)

for %%G in (%exts%) do (
set ext=%%G
set ext=!ext:~0,3!
reg add "HKCU\Software\Classes\.%%G" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "IE.AssocFile.!ext!" /f >nul
)

set exts=%exts%,MHT,MHTML,URL
set acl=%temp%\acl_%random%%random%.txt

for %%G in (%exts%) do (
set key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.%%G\UserChoice
echo !key! [1 7 17]>"%acl%"
regini "%acl%" >nul
set ext=%%G
set ext=!ext:~0,3!
reg add "!key!" /v "Progid" /t REG_SZ /d "IE.AssocFile.!ext!" /f >nul
)
del "%acl%" 2>nul

REM -- reset MIME associations
for %%G in (message/rfc822,text/html) do (
set key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\MIMEAssociations\%%G\UserChoice
reg add "!key!" /v "Progid" /t REG_SZ /d "IE.%%G" /f >nul
)

REM -- reset URL protocols
for %%A in (FTP,HTTP,HTTPS) do (
set key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\%%A\UserChoice
reg add "!key!" /v "Progid" /t REG_SZ /d "IE.%%A" /f >nul
for %%B in (DefaultIcon,shell) do (
set key=HKCU\Software\Classes\%%A
reg delete "!key!\%%B" /f >nul 2>&1
reg copy "HKCR\IE.%%A\%%B" "!key!\%%B" /s /f >nul
reg add "!key!" /v "EditFlags" /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f >nul
reg add "!key!" /v "URL Protocol" /t REG_SZ /d "" /f >nul
))

REM -- reset the start menu Internet link (Vista and earlier)
reg add "HKCU\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "IEXPLORE.EXE" /f

REM -- reset cached icons
if %xhtml% == 1 (
ie4uinit -cleariconcache
) else (
taskkill /im explorer.exe /f >nul
start explorer
)

pause
exit /b
```

### Remarks

> Any web browser application can register to appear as an Internet client on the Start menu. This visibility, coupled with proper registration for an application's [file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144104(v=vs.85).aspx) and [protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa767743(v=vs.85).aspx) types, gives an application default browser status. The default web browser is used for launching arbitrary URLs from anywhere in the system.
>
> **Note** Existing [start menu link] registrations are ignored in Windows 7 and later. This registration is deprecated as of Windows 7.
>
> <sub>Source: [How to Register an Internet Browser or Email Client With the Windows Start Menu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd203067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</sub>

­­

> The hierarchical registry structure for file and protocol associations gives precedence to per-user defaults over machine-level defaults.
>
> <sub>Source: [Default Programs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</sub>

Comment: Doesn't reset IE as default for me on Windows 8.1. :(

Comment: @techie007 What about the Default Programs settings in the control panel? Did anything change there? Did you get any errors while executing the batch script?

Comment: Seems to works under Windows 7 (Pro, 64-bit), but under Windows 8 (Pro 32-bit) it just shows the (same/usual) output "The operation completed successfully." -- "Press any key to continue . . ." but doesn't actually set IE as the default.

Comment: Under my other Windows 8 machine, it worked a little better.  I run it, and then next time I open a http link, it asks me which browser I want to use.  This is good enough by me, as other bits and pieces all seem (AFAICT) to think IE is registered as the default after doing that. So have my bounty. :)

Comment: @techie007 I totally forgot that Microsoft has [changed the rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848047.aspx) and now there's an anti-tampering protection for most of those registry keys. If you're willing to test it, I can send you an updated version of the script which would just clear the association in Windows 8 and later so that the next time you open a link or a html file, Windows would let you choose which browser to use. That's probably the best you can achieve in an automated way because (some) user interaction would be required anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can add below two lines in a bat file

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /f /v "Check_Associations" /d "yes" /t REG_SZ

reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice" /f /v "ProgId" /d "IE.HTTP" /t REG_SZ
```

After running the bat, reboot/log off and log back since above two command lines are meant to change registry values..

Aditinal details can be found here

(Fixed)-Cant set Internet Explorer as the Default Browser !
http://www.windowstechinfo.com/2016/03/fixed-cant-set-internet-explorer-as-the-default-browser.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about setting the default browser from the command line, but you can set and enforce it for the domain via group policy.

Here's something to get you started:

> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147307%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the `start` to get the command or batch file to work.

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://server_ip/home_page
```

Comment: We're (well _I am_ anyway) looking for solutions on setting the default browser from the command-line, not just to solve the example problem/reason in the OP.

Answer (score -1):

For Windows 8 (IE 10+) it's easy VBS script:

```
Dim URL 
Dim IE 
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
URL = "res://ieframe.dll/defaultbrowser.htm" 
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate URL


 Do While IE.Busy
    WScript.Sleep 100
 Loop

IE.Document.getElementById("changeDefaultButton").Click
```

It will start IE page for changing IE as default and simulate click on button for accept.