# Have a Windows 7 program take all its defaults in Default Programs via a script

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set Internet Explorer as the default browser from the command line](https://superuser.com/questions/300770/set-internet-explorer-as-the-default-browser-from-the-command-line)

Is there a way, via `cmd.exe` or a script, to invoke the "Set this program as default" for Internet Explorer in the "Set Default Programs" control panel applet?

A recent Adobe update seems to be bombarding our systems with automatic Google Chrome installations, with setting it as the default browser.  This is causing shortcuts to ActiveX applications on user's desktops to not work.  I'd like to create a small script we can tell users to run to reset this if this happens.

[image: This is an image of the relevant Windows 7 control panel and options.]

Comment: The first thing that springs to mind is using the `assoc` and `ftype` commands, but based on the information in [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/204354/how-do-i-get-ftype-assoc-to-match-windows-explorer), they might not even work. So I guess that leaves just editing the registry directly, which can be messy business.